# Как вырезать из псд пнг с эффектами?

Tags: png, photoshop

Есть псдшка, вот там есть такой элемент
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я оставляю включенным только этот слой, и все его эффекты - то вот что получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убирать эти эффекты - нельзя, но нужно как то преобразовать это в пнг с эффектами.. Как это сделать? Можно на урок ссылку, если есть откуда почитать

Интересно было бы узнать кто пользуется и какими скриптами/макросами/плагинами для фотошопа, облегчающими задачи подобного рода.

Comment: Вам не кажется ваш вопрос оффтопиком? У нас же тут не форум дизайнеров.

Comment: @VladD вот мне ваще кажется, с другой стороны, в фотошопе есть скриптинг и т.д. ... с очень большой натяжкой это можно признать..

Comment: @strangeqargo: Ну, если бы в вопросе был хоть намёк на скриптинг...

Comment: @VladD намекнул.

Comment: я бы кстати заскриптовал сборку пустых слоев, или слоев имеющих слишком мало пикселей, чтобы влият на изображение. в больших проектах полезно знать, какие слои можно убрать без прокликивания

Answer (score 4):

1. Продублируйте слой непосредственно с мечом;
2. Поставьте этот слой самым верхним;
3. Сведите все слои под ним (ваш меч, фон и все эффекты);
4. Получите два слоя - полностью сведенный и сверху слой с мечом;
5. Применяйте меч сверху как маску к слою снизу;
6. Экспортируйте.

Answer (score 3):

вот эти прямоугольники полуразмыте - у тебя не эффекты, а слои (возможно, с масками прозрачности, скорее всего -нет - т.е. - альфа-каналы уже смерджены со слоями),
и да, у тебя, возможно не все лишние слои выключены

вырубай все слои по одному.

у тебя не должно остаться фоновых слоев - только мечик и сияние от его деталей.

тогда можно сохранять в пнг.

если все плохо, придется вырезать мечик отдельно и самому накладывать эффекты.

//привет от бывшего фотошопера